# How to remove a child from inside it if it doesn't know it is child

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, removechild

I got quite a nice title:)

My main class is

```
@interface StartLayer : CCScene
```

I used

```
HelpView* hp = [[HelpView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 520)];
CCUIViewWrapper* wrapper = [CCUIViewWrapper wrapperForUIView:hp];
[self addChild:wrapper];
```

to add class

```
@interface HelpView : UIView
```

I have got two more classes that have HelpView as their super class

```
@interface GameOverMenu : HelpView <UITextFieldDelegate>

@interface PlayScene : HelpView
```

In my GameOverMenu or PlayScene I need to remove HelpView (I guess all of subViews will be removed too) as a child of StartLayer and I totally need HelpView to have UIView as superclass. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[self.parent removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES] not working ?

Comment: I don't have such option in self.  I guess it would work if StartLayer is superclass for HelpView, but I need it to be UIView

Comment: Do StartLayer as a singleton, next set a tag to wrapper, wrapper.tag = (some enum or int) 1, and in HelpView you can get wrapper and remove it, ((CCUIViewWrapper*)[[StartLayer sharedInstance] getChildByTag:wrapper]) removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];